# variable written as an average in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I would to explain a variable as the average value of a resource pool's proprietes in particular in the section "failure" I want to know the average of time to repair. For doing that I've tried to insert in the initial value:" resource pool name.average(timetorepair).main()" but anylogic answer me that Time to repair isn't valid

Answer (score 0):

The "Actions" properties of your resource pool have 2 code boxes you can use:
[image]

"On failure", you can record the current model `time()` for the given `unit` (this is a keyword in the code box to refer to the actual resource pool unit having a failure).

Store that time in your unit agent (i.e. create a variable in it `FailureStartTime`) and call `unit.FailureStartTime = time()` in the "on failure" box

In the "on repair" code box, you can compute the total repair time as `time()-unit.FailureStartTime()`. Store that into a "Statistics" object and you can call `mean()` on that anytime